# Segmentation fault when using pointers

Tags: pointers

i have problems  with pointers in C++.

Here is the code:

```
char* _Ptr="Hello World";
*_Ptr='Q';
printf("-> %c\n",*_Ptr);
```

During execution the programm crashed.
So i tried to debug the programm and when debugging the programm i received the following error:

```
Segmentation Fault
```

Comment: See if it works better with `char _Ptr[] = "Hello World";` for the first statement.  If so, perhaps the compiler is storing the string constant where you're not allowed to assign.  Not unreasonable, actually.

Comment: Thank you for you help